# How to subclass complex in python3

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I'm doing an optimisation on the complex plane, with an expensive function.

I'd like to have a class that's a complex number, which behaves like a complex number for arithmetic, but also has the result of the function, and a few convenient debug assists tacked onto it.

I threw the following together, and it was only later that I realised I didn't understand why it should be working, as I'd initially omitted the call to `super().__init__()`. I don't understand how the z argument is setting the .real and .imag parts of the number, or that it's not throwing an error at me. When I added the super(), it still worked exactly the same. However, super doesn't take an argument, so I don't see how that would magic the parameter z into .real and .imag either.

```
def spam(z):
    return abs(pow(z,3))

class Point(complex):
    def __init__(self, z):
        # super().__init__()    # doesn't seem to make any difference
        # super().__init__(z)   # throws an error

        try:
            Point.serial += 1
        except AttributeError:
            Point.serial = 0
        self.id = Point.serial

        self.y = spam(z)
        self.ge3 = self.y>=3       

    def __str__(self):
        return 'point {} ({}+{}j) = {} {}'.format(self.id,
                                                  self.real,
                                                  self.imag,
                                                  self.y,
                                                  ('below', 'above')[self.ge3])

p = Point(3)
q = Point(2j)
r = Point((p+q)/2)
print(p)
print(q)
print(r)
```

gives

```
point 0 (3.0+0.0j) = 27 above
point 1 (0.0+2.0j) = 8.0 above
point 2 (1.5+1.0j) = 5.859020822628983 above
```

Is this legal or expected behaviour? How is it working? Should I do it differently? Is it likely to stop working with future versions (3.5.2 presently)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Your code is fine, the magic method `__new__` inherited from `complex` is what actually creates your object, and it was actually called *before* the object initialization.

Calling `super().__init__()` would still be a better practice though.

### Long answer

The method `__init__` does not create your object, it only initializes it after creation. The method that creates it is called `__new__`. Have a look at the following code.

```
class Point(complex):
    def __init__(self, z):
        print(self)

x = Point(1+1j) # This prints (1+1j)
```

When `__init__` is called, the object has already been created. But here is what happens if we were to override the `__new__` method.

```
class Point(complex):
    def __new__(*args):
        return 0 # We purposedly return without calling super().__new__(*args)

    def __init__(self, z):
        print(self)

x = Point(1+1j) # x has value 0

x.imag # That fails
```

Here we indeed cannot call `x.imag` since `complex.__new__` was never called. Notice that `__init__` was not even called here, we will see why below.

In your code, the method `complex.__new__` is called (namely with argument `z`) and returns a `complex` subclassed as a `Point`, which is then the object passed as `self` to `__init__`.

In general the flow is the following:

1. `MyType.__new__` is called when you do `MyType(...)` and it returns an object
2. If the object returned by `MyType.__new__` is an instance of `MyType`, then it is passed as `self` to `MyType.__init__`
3. Otherwise, `MyType.__init__` isn't called at all, this is what happened in the second example we saw

It is rare that you will actually need to override the `__new__` method. Since you cannot really create an object there is little you can do other than call the [type method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) or `super().__new__` that cannot be done in `__init__`. It is mostly useful when it comes to [metaclass, which are a lot of fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python).

Comment: You'll notice my call to `super().__init__()` takes no parameters. I did first try it with a parameter z, and I got the error 'takes no parameters'.

Comment: You are correct, I will update. I believe that in this case, super().__init__ does nothing at all so you can omit it.